# Stream JSON-parsable array to file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stream

So you're reading data from a file, cleaning out the data, and writing it back to another file, but the new file isn't accepted JSON format.

---

You need to fill an object in the new file. You get a chunk from the file, alter it, and save it to the new file.

For this you stream the data out, edit the chunks, and stream it back into the other file. Great.

You're sure to add `,` after each item to keep the array readable later on,
but now the last item has a trailing comma `,`...

You don't know the count of items in the original file, and you also don't know when the reader is at the last item.

You use something like [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) on that array but `JSONStream` also does not provide the index.
The only end events are for your `writers` and `readers`.

**How do you remove the trailing comma before/after writing?**

```
read_file = 'animals.json' //very large file
write_file = 'brown_dogs.json' //moderately large file

let read_stream = fs.createReadStream(read_file);
let write_stream = fs.createWriteStream(write_file);
let dog_stream = require('JSONStream').parse('array_of_animals.dogs.*');


write_stream
    .on('finish', () => {
        //the writer is done writing my list of dogs, but my array has a
        //trailing comma, now my brown_dogs.json isn't parsable
    })
    .write('{"brown_dogs": ['); //lets start

read_stream
    .pipe(dog_stream)
    .on('data', dog => {
    //basic logic before we save the item 
        if (dog._fur_colour === 'brown'){
            let _dog = {
                    type : dog._type,
                    colour : dog._fur_colour,
                    size : dog._height
                }
            };
            //we write our accepted dog
            write_stream.write(JSON.stringify(_dog) + ',');
        }
    })
    .on('end', () => {
       //done reading animals.json
        write_stream.write(']}');
    })
```

--

If your resulting JSON file is small, you may simply add all the dogs to an array and only save all the contents to the file in one go. This means the file is not only JSON friendly, but also small enough to simply open with `JSON.parse()`

If your resulting JSON file is large, you may need to stream the items out in any case. Luckily `JSONStream` allows us to not only extract each dog individually but also ignore the trailing comma.

This is what I understand to be the solution...but I don't think it's perfect. Why can't the file be accepted JSON, regardless of the size.

Comment: What is the actual question or error?

Comment: How would you remove the comma after the last item on a writeStream.

Comment: This is a great/simple solution to write large JSON data in chunks. Thanks @KevinPotgieter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually very simple.
Add an empty string `var` to the beginning of the insert. Set the string to a separator after the first insert.

```
//update this string after the first insert
let separator = '';

read_stream
    .pipe(dog_stream)
    .on('data', dog => {
        //basic logic before we save the item 
        if (dog._fur_colour === 'brown'){
            let _dog = {
                    type : dog._type,
                    colour : dog._fur_colour,
                    size : dog._height
                }
            };
            //we write our accepted dog
            write_stream.write(separator + JSON.stringify(_dog));

            //update this after first insert
            separator = ',';
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

I added `toJSONArray` method exactly for this in `scramjet` [see docs here](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet/blob/HEAD/docs/data-stream.md#DataStream+toJSONArray). It puts a comma only between the chunks.

The code would look like this:

```
fs.createReadStream(read_file)
    .pipe(require('JSONStream').parse('array_of_animals.dogs.*'))
    .pipe(new DataStream())
    .filter(dog => dog._fur_colour === 'brown') // this will filter out the non-brown dogs.
    .map(dog => { // remap the data
        reutrn {
            type : dog._type,
            colour : dog._fur_colour,
            size : dog._height
        };
    })
    .toJSONArray(['{"brown_dogs": [', ']}']) // add your enclosure
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(write_file));
```

This code should make a fine JSON.